# What is the proper handling of an SSL request where SSL is not enabled?

Tags: ssl, https

Quick question.  I have a server I am managing which does NOT use https.  When I attempt to go to the website with an https url, I get a bizzarre error which is the result of the fact that I have more than one website on this webserver.

So I am tweaking the webserver config so it handles https requests to non-https websites properly, the only problem is, I do not know what the "standard practice" is with respect to this scenario.

I am not willing to buy an SSL certificate for this domain, what I need is the standard error procedure that I should follow when this type of bad request is encountered.

My understanding is that it is not possible to redirect the traffic to http because the client requires SSL authentication in order to trust any output from my webserver.  Therefore it is even more unclear to me what is the "correct" behviour.  Should I simply just drop the connection and do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reject traffic on the 443 port until you will get SSL certificate.